# SSRS ReportViewer report content in line with scroll bar?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, reporting-services, reportviewer

How I can make that all the content don't be in a new line, but be in the same line, with other content part in Microsoft ReportViever control(MVC) when reports loaded from SQL reporting services? I'm using MVCReportViewer.

**Example:** when tables or other content reach the bounds of the report, they are in a new line with duplicating headers...How I can make that that it would be in same line and when it reaches the report bounds, it automatically adds scroll bar..?

**Here is how is now :**
[image]

**And here is how I want:** 
[image]